# I can't close menu when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

AM trying to have to actions on a nav menu (open and close)
this is my code :

Here, i can open the item and hide it when i click outside BUT I need also to close the item when i click on the link `.menu-item-has-children > a`

```js
var click_item = function() {
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function() {
  var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');

  if ($(this).attr('href') === "#") {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
    console.log("ppppp");
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false);
    $(this).removeClass('is-opened');
    EltToToggle.removeClass('show');
    console.log("click true")
  } else if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "false") {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true);
    $(this).addClass('is-opened');
    EltToToggle.addClass('show');
    console.log("click false")
  }
});
}
click_item();



$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var sub_menu = $(".sub-menu");

    // If the target of the click isn't the sub_menu
    if (!sub_menu.is(e.target) && sub_menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      sub_menu.removeClass('show');
      $(".menu-item-has-children > a").attr('aria-expanded', false);
      $(".menu-item-has-children > a").removeClass('is-opened');
      console.log("ok")
    }
    click_item();
  });
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
.menu-item-has-children>a {
position: relative
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
}

.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    content: "\f077";
    font-family: FontAwesome!important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-alt: "";
    speak: none;
    right: 1.6rem;
    top: 2.3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: -webkit-transform .25s ease;
    transition: transform .25s ease;
    transition: transform .25s ease,-webkit-transform .25s ease;
}
.menu-item-has-children>a:after {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
}
 .menu-item-has-children>a[aria-expanded=true]:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                               Item 1
           </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Link 2
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                                Link 2
         </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Lvl2. Children 3 with children
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Comment: are you getting any console errors when executing the code?

Comment: You should prepare jsfiddle of such a bug. It will be helpful.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit, scroll down and edit snippet  - add HTML

Comment: Why not just `$(".sub-menu").on("click",function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    $(".menu-item-has-children > a").attr('aria-expanded', false);
    $(".menu-item-has-children > a").removeClass('is-opened');
});`

Comment: can't edit the snippet cause i have many css class and html to show, it's hard to put the code in order and it takes time ><

Comment: @mplungjan what is it for ?!!!

Comment: If you cannot be bothered to show the HTML so we can help you perhaps use more clever code, then we cannot help. My comment above I was just guessing

Comment: PS: i can also hide the item when clickin on the it, it's a kind of toggle (add/remove class)  but this is the problem actually :(

Comment: @mplungjan ok here is a simple explain : user click on the link and it show the item, he can also hide it when he click on it (kind of toggle on the lin), also he can hide it when he clicks outside the link and that's works good but he can't hide it when he clicks on the link..I want to hide the item when i click on the link :)  is it clear ? :/

Comment: @mplungjan i made some code in the snippet can you check please ?

Comment: Thanks. What is expected behaviour? Right now the sub menues do not open

Comment: We need class show etc

Comment: @mplungjan done! pease check

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide/show your navigation bar using css class, that will be easy and effective way to manage it.

Also replace `$(document).mouseup` with `$(document).click`, you just need clicking event, so I recommend to avoid using `mouseup` in such scenarios.

You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).click(function(event) {
    var clickover = $(event.target);
    // if the user click outside navbar
    if (!clickover.hasClass("navbar")) {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("in");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.navbar.in {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="navbar in"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Click **outside** the navbar and it'll be closed. This is just a **DEMO** that can help you understand how to hide/show elements by clicking events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

If there are no submenus, close all parent uls with class show

I also converted the if to a toggle

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children  a').on('click', function() {
  var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');

  if ($(this).attr('href') === "#") {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  const expanded = $(this).attr('aria-expanded') === "true"

  $(this).attr('aria-expanded',    !expanded);
  $(this).toggleClass('is-opened', !expanded);
  EltToToggle.toggleClass('show',  !expanded);

  if (EltToToggle.length === 0) {
      $(this).parents("ul,show").toggleClass("show",false)
  }

});


$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var sub_menu = $(".sub-menu");

  // If the target of the click isn't the sub_menu
  if (!sub_menu.is(e.target) && sub_menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    sub_menu.removeClass('show');
    $(".menu-item-has-children > a").attr('aria-expanded', false);
    $(".menu-item-has-children > a").removeClass('is-opened');
    console.log("ok")
  }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                               Item 1
           </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Link 2
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">
                                Link 2
         </a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl2. Children 1
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#">
                                Lvl2. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                                Lvl2. Children 3 with children
            </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">
                                Lvl3. Children 1
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" aria-current="page">
                                [Current] Lvl3. Children 2 with long text lorem ipsum
            </a>

          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl3. Children 3
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="external-link">
                                [_blank] Lvl2. Children 4
            <span class="icon-link-external" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>



</ul>
```

Comment: i have exactly the same result in my code, but i want to close the item when i click on the link too

Comment: All links without a search submenu close the menus in this code I do not know what you mean

Comment: the link is supposed to work as a toggle that show and also hide the item...normally there is also a small chevron which changes when the item is displayed or hidden

Comment: As it does here. I do not know what my code does not do for you

Comment: it does not hide the item when i click in the link (when the item is shown)

Comment: It does for me. That is why I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: When i click on the link, it just shows the item, when i click on the link a second time to hide it, it doesn't work !

Comment: Ok I give up. You have 90% of what it seems you need

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("*").click(function(){
    $(".menu-item-has-children > a").removeClass('is-opened');
  });
});
```

Comment: Still no evidence this is needed

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.